# How safe it is to store keys in Electrum? I think Luke Dash JR didn't recommend it

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, electrum, offline, offline-transactions

I agree with Luke Dash Jr and in general this wiki with the fact that doing anything without a full node is a mistake:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Clearing_Up_Misconceptions_About_Full_Nodes

But my question was in terms of just storing the keys in the Electrum wallet format to use in an offline gapped computer to sign the transactions and then broadcast on other full node computer online. Im just paranoid about the whole seed model. I reckon reading something to do with key derivation where if an attacker knew a private key of only one of your addresses and something else, they could somehow know subsequent addresses. Something to do with key derivation or something. I think this has something to do with it.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5265935.0

Im so paranoid to use anything but wallet.dat Bitcoin Core format that im not sure if missing on the clear advantage that being able to "spawn" your wallet anywhere in the world by remembering 12 words delivers, however, im concerned that you give away on security by using this. Why Bitcoin Core does not give you this method of wallet of knowing 12 words and being able to spawn your wallet if there were no tradeoffs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a reason to why Bitcoin Core does not implement BIP39?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88237/is-there-a-reason-to-why-bitcoin-core-does-not-implement-bip39)

Comment: Not really. Andrew Chow explained how BIP39 isn't considered secure and that is why Core does not implement it. But then he also explains Electrum does not use this anymore, yet Electrum still give you the option to spawn wallets with 12 words. On the Electrum website they say:

"Electrum 2.0 derives keys and addresses from a hash of the UTF8 normalized seed phrase with no dependency on a fixed wordlist.".

So the question would be, why isn't Core using this method for wallets then? Electrum devs still consider secure the "show 12 words for seed" method when creating wallet, why not Core?

Comment: Core wallet has lot of things which are different from Electrum. Not saying every wallet needs to be same but if you want to know the reasons, will have to search related PRs, issues or open a PR to see the response from other regular contributors.

Comment: What is a PR? @Prayank

Comment: PR: Pull Request

Comment: Isn't that for coders only? a PR is to propose a code on github as far as I know, it's not a forum. Im not an expert enough to ask in that context so I came here in the forum.

Comment: Anyway, it's still not clear to me. Can someone a core dev to explain?